# Is there a way to solve $\arcsin\left(\frac{d}{r}\cdot \sin(x)\right)=\phi-x+\frac{\theta}{2}$ for $x$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

While solving a geometry problem, I derived the following equation:

$$\arcsin\left(\frac{d}{r}\cdot \sin(x)\right)=\phi-x+\frac{\theta}{2}$$

And, in order to solve such problem, I need to solve for $x$, but I see no way to do that.

Comment: Not solvable with "pencil and paper" methods.

Comment: This equation implies $d\sin x = r\sin(\phi - x + \theta/2)$, in case that's easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\arcsin\left(\frac{d}{r}\cdot \sin(x)\right)=\phi-x+\frac{\theta}{2}$$

$$\frac{d}{r}\cdot \sin(x)=\sin \left(\phi-x+\frac{\theta}{2} \right)$$

$$\frac{d}{r}\cdot \sin(x)=\sin \left(\phi+\frac{\theta}{2} \right)\cos \left(x\right)-\cos \left(\phi+\frac{\theta}{2} \right)\sin \left(x \right)$$

$$\sin(x) \left(\frac{d}{r}+ \cos \left(\phi+\frac{\theta}{2} \right)\right)=\sin \left(\phi+\frac{\theta}{2} \right)\cos \left(x\right)$$

$$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin \left(\phi+\frac{\theta}{2} \right)}{\frac{d}{r}+ \cos \left(\phi+\frac{\theta}{2} \right)} $$

Comment: There ya go. +1 for you.